# Anonymous spam comments when only registered users can comment

Tags: comments, spam

I have WordPress website where only registered users could write comments. 
But for some reasons I get anonymous spam comments time to time.

This comments don't have any information about user that leaved it. Also I have captcha on registration form.

1. How this comments are got in my website?
2. What can I do to prevent it in future?

Comment: Do you have the Akismet (or any other) anti spam plug-in?

Comment: I don't have any anti-spam plugin but I use reCaptcha on registration form and also captcha on login form. I don't understand hove this comments are added from non-registered users.

Comment: Comments spam is a big headache. Use a plugin to confirm an email after the comment is posted. Captcha's may not work if the site is not secured properly because then it's easier to add comments. Try using Disqus.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have alot of bots creating the fake usernames/pass.  If you're using Buddypress then you will get lots of bots.  Try [NoMoreCaptchas](http://nomorecaptchas.com/#!/what-does-it-do), it authenticates the user as a human or bot via a new type of technology called [BioChronometrics](https://oxford-biochron.com/about).  This is super fast for the user since it is completely passive authentication.  It's based on user behavior.

Comment: But if bots are registered no matter that I have captcha on registration form, why I don't see any new users and this spam comments are not connected to any registered user. So I think that it is problem with comments not user registrations.

Comment: Turn off trackbacks and pingbacks in the WordPress Discussion Settings. They are a back door for spam to exploit no matter what kind of protection you have.

Comment: both of this checkboxes are unchecked in site Settings -> Discussion page. Or I am missing something?